# counting 0 singular values in a product of random matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, random-graphs, random-matrices

Can anyone suggest a way to bound expected number of 0 eigenvalues in the following product of random matrices?

$G_1 B_1 G_2 B_2 \ldots G_n B_n$

where $G_i$ is $d$-by-$d$ with entries sampled from standard normal, while $B_i$ has 0,1 entries sampled uniformly.

It seems as $n$ grows, an increasing number of singular values are going to 0.
[image]

For instance, for $d=256, n=100$, I'm seeing 5-25 non-zero eigenvalues in this product ([notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/newton/integer-gaussian-matrix-product.nb))

Comment: Are you sure you're seeing matrices with actual nontrivial kernel vs. very small singular values? Numerically it is very hard to distinguish those two things. Seems like the $B_i$ can give nontrivial kernel, though.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I've tried with precision 10,000 and seeing the same results. After 20 iters, so eigenvalues seem to be exactly zero. It could be limitation of algorithm used by Mathematica (https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/newton/integer-gaussian-matrix-product.nb)

Comment: OK, looks like they are not exactly zero, there was default cut-off which removed them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that I am using exact arithmetic rather than numerical.

Given two $d \times d$ matrices $B$ and $C$, consider $BGC$ where $G$ is a random matrix with a density in $\mathbb R^{d \times d}$ (e.g. Gaussian). 
Let $r_C$ and $n_C$ be the rank and nullity of $C$, and similarly $r_B$ and $n_B$.  $\text{ran}(C)$ is a vector
space of dimension $r_C = \text{rank}(C)$.  With probability $1$, $(G (\text{ran}(C))) \cap \ker(B) = \{0\}$ if that is possible, i.e. unless $r_C + n_B > d$, which is equivalent to $n_B > n_C$.  Thus if $n_B \le n_C$, $n_{BGC} = n_C$ with probability $1$. Similarly, if
$n_B \ge n_C$, $n_{BGC} = n_{C^\top G^\top B^\top} = n_{B^\top} = n_B$.  So with probability $1$, $n_{G_1 B_1 G_2 B_2 \ldots G_n B_n} = \max(n_{B_1}, \ldots, n_{B_n})$.

So yes, $n_{G_1\ldots B_n}$ (which is the geometric multiplicity of the eigenvalue $0$) is always nondecreasing with $n$; we have $\mathbb P(n_{G_1 \ldots B_n}) \ge k) = 1 - \mathbb P(n_{B_i} < k)^n$. With probability $1$, $n_{G_1 \ldots B_n}$ will eventually hit $d$, simply because eventually some $B_n$ will be the $0$ matrix.  But the expected value of the $n$ for which that first happens will be $2^{d^2}$.

EDIT: 
In fact it seems to me that as $d$ increases, the probability that $B_i$ is invertible goes rapidly to $1$.  So in your example ($d=256$, $n=100$), it is extremely likely that all your matrices were actually invertible and any eigenvalues of $0$ were artifacts of round-off error in floating-point arithmetic.